# Random для ArrayList

Tags: c#

Сделал заполнение коллекции рандомными элементами. Вопрос, как добавить в рандом буквы? И задавать длину элемента?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.Write("Введит количество элементов коллекции: ");
        int i = Int32.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        ArrayList list = NewCollection(i);
        WriteMyCollection(list);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
    public static ArrayList NewCollection(int i)
    {
        Random rand = new Random();
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            arr.Add(rand.Next());
        return arr;
    }

    public static void WriteMyCollection(ArrayList arr)
    {
        foreach (int a in arr)
            Console.Write("{0}\t", a);
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
    }
```

Comment: А какого типа элементы вы хотите в коллекции? Символы? Строки? Какой длины строки, в каких пределах? (И почему нетипизированная коллекция, 2016 год на дворе же!)

Comment: элементами должны быть строки. длина элемента должна задаваться пользователем(как и кол-во элементов). это учебное задание, на тестирование производительности коллекций, поэтому и выбор кажется странным))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ну например так:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
    var collectionLength = 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < collectionLength; i++)
        al.Add(CreateRandomString());
    foreach (var s in al)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
}

static Random r = new Random();
static int maxStringLength = 10;

static string chars = "01234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
static string CreateRandomString()
{
    var length = r.Next(maxStringLength) + 1;
    var sb = new StringBuilder(length);
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        var randomIndex = r.Next(chars.Length);
        sb.Append(chars[randomIndex]);
    }
    return sb.ToString();
}
```

У меня вывело:

> 1JE
>   I0v7e4Tz4
>   AYq7QLXc
>   a17EEP
>   25Kke
>   A5cNhWu5D6
>   tbduDUIhO0
>   QAvQh
>   2OOJsEnkT
>   t
>   H
>   wVc0r
>   Vn012q
>   7eChqEG2
>   g00xP9JQe
>   6FW
>   nknHSDDMG2
>   g6gL2l1rG
>   30UKMEj
>   Lj60jeX2